# Prevent view to urlencode contextual filters

Tags: 7, views

I have 2 views.

View 1 is a small exposed form which collects some data and has some contextual filters.

View 1 is linked to View 2, so when the form is submitted the form redirects to View 2 and inserts the collected data as contextual filters in the url.

The fields in the url are in the form of `module[module_field]` but they are printed as `module%5Bmodule_field%5D` in the addressbar in the browser when View 1 redirects to View 2.

But opening manually the same page with the decoded version `module[module_field]` works.
How can I prevent View 1 to urlencode the parameters for the contextual filters?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use theme_links() function in template.php file of your theme. The original theme_links() function has this:

```
if (isset($link['href'])) {
  // Pass in $link as $options, they share the same keys.
  $output .= l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link);
}

You should replace it with this to undo the encoding:

if (isset($link['href'])) {
  // Pass in $link as $options, they share the same keys.
  $link_html = l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link);
  // Decode the link HTML before adding it to the output
  $link_html = rawurldecode($link_html);
  $output .= $link_html;
}
```